# How to determine which side of a rectangle was crossed by the mouse

Tags: c#, winforms, rect

I'm working on a sort of game in which the mouse is bounded by a rectangle using the following code:

```
    Rectangle box = new Rectangle(113, 113, 276, 276);
    char direction;

    private void Form1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (box.Contains(e.Location))
        {
            temp = new Point(e.Location.X, e.Location.Y + 23);
        }
        else
        {
            Cursor.Position = temp;
        }
    }
```

I need to determine whichever side the mouse tries to cross and set the char direction to 'n', 's', 'e', or 'w'. I tried a series of if statements:

```
    // West - East
    if (e.Location.X < temp.X)
    {
        direction = 'w';
    }

    if (e.Location.X > temp.X)
    {
        direction = 'e';
    }

    // North - South
    if (e.Location.Y + 23 < temp.Y)
    {
        direction = 'n';
    }

    if (e.Location.Y + 23 > temp.Y)
    {
        direction = 's';
    }
```

The problem is that if the mouse approaches the east or west sides at an angle, it will return north or south. Due to the nature of points, a statement that returns true on the W-E axis can simultaneously return true on  the N-S axis. How can I make is so it will return the correct wall regardless of the angle at which it contacts the edge?

Comment: Did `Cursor.Clip = new Rectangle(box.Location, box.Size);` sort the boundary issue for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect the problem is that you only set `temp` when its inside the box, not outside, this code works:

```
Rectangle box = new Rectangle(113, 113, 276, 276);
char direction;
Point temp;

private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    using (Graphics g = this.CreateGraphics())
    {
        Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Black, 2);
        g.DrawRectangle(pen, box);
        pen.Dispose();
    }
}

private void Form1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    temp = new Point(e.Location.X, e.Location.Y);    
    if (box.Contains(temp.X, temp.Y))
    {
        textBox1.Text = temp.X + " , " + temp.Y;
    }
    else
    {
        //COMMENT OUT THIS LINE FOR MOVEMENTS OUTSIDE THE Box
        if (textBox1.Text.Length == 1) return;

        if (box.Left >= temp.X)
        {
            direction = 'w';
        }
        else if (box.Left + box.Width <= temp.X)
        {
            direction = 'e';
        }
        else if (box.Top >= temp.Y)
        {
            direction = 'n';
        }

        else if (box.Top + box.Height <= temp.Y)
        {
            direction = 's';
        }

        textBox1.Text = direction.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code correctly determines the wall which was hit, however, the mouse is no longer bounded by the rectangle.

Comment: Sorry some stuff has come up, so I'll let you implement this 2nd part to the solution... `Cursor.Clip = new Rectangle(box.Location, box.Size);` as per https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.cursor.clip(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2